# Prove $Ax=\lambda x \implies A^n x = \lambda^n x$ for matrix A and eigenvalue $\lambda$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

For a matrix $A$ with $Ax=\lambda x$, how can we prove that $A^nx=\lambda^nx$? It seems like it should be trivial, but I'm missing something.

(I'm new to this material, so simple language is appreciated.) Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that $A^nx=A^{n-1}(Ax)=A^{n-1}\lambda x= \lambda(A^{n-1}x)$. Since the scalar $\lambda$ commutes with all linear transformations by definition.

Can you finish this off by induction?

If you need to see the induction, it is below.

> $A^0x=x=\lambda^0 x$, and if $A^{n-1}x=\lambda^{n-1}x$, then we have by the above that $A^{n}x=\lambda(A^{n-1}x)=\lambda\lambda^{n-1}x=\lambda^nx$. Thus the induction holds, and for all $n\ge 0$, $A^{n}x=\lambda^n x$.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** $A^nx = A^{n - 1} (Ax)$.

Comment: A relatively better "**Hint:**" might be $A^n x = A(A^{n-1}x)$. But both are actually not worth an answer.

Comment: @quid This is a really trivial question and hints aren't supposed to be posted as comments. This way people can see that the question is actually already answered without checking the comment section. See also [this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/10589/259493).

Comment: As you could see I know that meta-post. That "hint" is potentially totally unhelpful and the question is not answered at all.

Answer (score 1):

One thing you should recall is that multiplication with scalars can be interchanged with multiplication by a matrix.

Let us consider the case $n=2$. So $A^2 x$. That is equal to $A  (A x)$. And using $Ax = \lambda x$ this is $A (\lambda x)$. Now this is $\lambda (A  x)$, by the property recalled and further  $\lambda ( \lambda x)= \lambda^2 x$.

Now, based on this idea you can set up a proof by induction on $n$.